# Bash - default size in printf

Tags: bash

I am writing a script that lists each process pid, ppid, user, group , cwdir, etc. In the terminal into a table.
The script when executed as non-root user wont get some of the values so it has to print instead white spaces in the table, but printf is not doing so:

```
> foo=foo
> bar=

> printf "%3.3s$3.3s end\n" $bar $foo
```

So I want to get something like this

```
   foo end
```

But I get this

```
foo    end
```

It is like it switches the white spaces rightmost

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of the way `bash` interprets command lines, double-quotes are needed around any argument that might either (a) be empty or (b) contain whitespace.  Try:

```
$ printf "%3s%3s end\n" "$bar" "$foo"
   foo end
```

#### Explanation

Without double quotes around it, an empty shell variable is not kept as an empty argument; it is simply removed from the command line.  For example, consider:

```
$ printf "%3s%3s end\n" $bar $foo
foo    end
```

With `bar` empty, the above is equivalent to:

```
$ printf "%3s%3s end\n" $foo
foo    end
```

By adding double-quotes, `bash` will keep "$bar" as an empty instead of removing it all together.